# Contact Picker get Email address

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, peoplepicker

I'm using the ContactPicker class to integrate the Windows 8 People App in my application.
When Clicked on a button I load the People App. The user picks some friends and I would like to display their Name, Image and Email address in a ListView.

I have no problems with displaying the name and the image. Instead of showing the email address it shows: **System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]** Any solutions??

```
    IReadOnlyList<GetContactDetails> ConDetails;
    public IReadOnlyList<GetContactDetails> ContactDetails
    {
        get { return ConDetails; }
        set { ConDetails = value; }
    }

    List<GetContactDetails> Contact;
    public List<GetContactDetails> SetContacts
    {
        get { return Contact; }
        set { Contact = value; }
    }

    private async void Contacts_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetContacts = new List<App1.GetContactDetails>();
        var contactSelector = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPicker();
        contactSelector.CommitButtonText = "Pick contact";

        var SelectedContact = await contactSelector.PickMultipleContactsAsync();
        foreach (var item in SelectedContact)
        {
            SetContacts.Add(new GetContactDetails(item));
        }
        ContactList.ItemsSource = SetContacts;
    }
```

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="ContactList" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource contactTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="271" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="585"/>


    <DataTemplate x:Key="contactTemplate">
        <Grid Width="400" Height="200" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="350"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="75"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="75"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="75"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Name" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="0"  Text="{Binding ContactName}" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Mail" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ContactEmails}"  FontSize="10" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
<!--<Image Height="100" Width="100" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding ContactImage}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Image>-->


        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

GetContactDetails class:

```
public class GetContactDetails
{
        public string ContactName { get; private set; }
        public BitmapImage ContactImage { get; private set; }
        public Visibility CanShow { get; set; }

        public List<string> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
        public List<string> ContactEmails { get; set; }

        public GetContactDetails(ContactInformation c)
        {
            PhoneNumbers = new List<string>();
            ContactEmails = new List<string>();

            CanShow = Visibility.Visible;
            ContactName = c.Name;
            if (c.PhoneNumbers.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in c.PhoneNumbers)
                {
                    PhoneNumbers.Add(item.Value);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                CanShow = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            GetContactImage(c);
        }

        async void GetContactImage(ContactInformation Img)
        {
            var imgStream = await Img.GetThumbnailAsync();
            ContactImage = new BitmapImage();
            if (imgStream != null && imgStream.Size > 0)
            {
                ContactImage.SetSource(imgStream);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you set the values in ContactEmails?  Does the user enter this somewhere?

Comment: The email address comes from the Windows 8 People application. The user can not enter this, he can only choose of which friend he would like to see the details.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something.  Somewhere the code needs to access that email list and set ContactEmails to it.  Where are you doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your code is not adding information to the ContactEmails.  Wouldn't you need something like this?

```
   public List<string> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    public List<string> ContactEmails { get; set; }

    public GetContactDetails(ContactInformation c)
    {
        PhoneNumbers = new List<string>();
        ContactEmails = new List<string>();

        CanShow = Visibility.Visible;
        ContactName = c.Name;
        if (c.PhoneNumbers.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in c.PhoneNumbers)
            {
                PhoneNumbers.Add(item.Value);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            CanShow = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        /// Don't you need the below code somewhere?//////
        if (c.Emails.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in c.Emails)
            {
                ContactEmails .Add(item.Value);
            }
        }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        else
        {
            CanShow = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        GetContactImage(c);
    }
```

Comment: I think the problem is at the System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]. This suggest I'm trying to show a list object instead of the values in the list.

Comment: True, but it's kind of hard to tell if we don't see where you are setting the ContactEmails to the email values.

Comment: I just thought about my answer and yeah, that won't work.  I added a new answer that is probably the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a TextBlock to a List.  You need to parse the ContactEmails into a separate string.  Perhaps like this:

Create a property called ContactEmailString

```
    string _contactEmailString;
    public string ContactEmailsString 
    {
      get{
          return _contactEmailString;
         }
      set
      {
         value=_contactEmailString;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("ContactEmailString");
      }
   }
```

Then in your function that sets the contact info do this:

```
foreach(var item in ContactEmails)
{
   ContactEmailString+=item+";";
}
```

Then in your xaml bind to ContactEmailString instead of ContactEmail.

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ContactEmailString}"  FontSize="10" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: Make sure that you implement INotifyPropertyChanged, it will be required to be able to bind to your ContactEmailString correctly